# Find a regular expression for binary strings to have odd non-empty blocks of 1s

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Write down a Regular Expression for the language $L$ consisting of all binary strings where every non-empty block of $1$s has odd length. (Notice that the empty string is in this language.)

My working out:

$$(111)^* 011$$

This way, there will always be an odd number of $1$s.

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the empty string.

Comment: How would you match an empty string?

Comment: Well...the pattern [1]* matches it, because it matches "1" taken $0$ or more times.

Comment: You might want to draw an FSA that achieves what you want; from that, deriving the regular expression can be done mechanically.

Comment: Maybe I'm rusty on my regular expressions, but this doesn't look right. For one, you can generate an expression with an odd number of ones (111111011) or (011). For another, the question seems to be asking for every block of 1's (set of ones walled in by zero) should have odd length. So if you generate (111011) this would still be wrong, because even though the whole string has an odd number of ones, the last block of ones is not odd in length.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your regular expression:

$$ (111)^* 011 \enspace. $$

It generates the strings $011$, $111011$, $111111011$, and so on.  None of these words is such that every nonempty block of $1$s has odd length.  Moreover, the total number of $1$s alternates between even and odd, contrary to your claim.  Even if we had guaranteed blocks of $1$s of odd lengths, as in

$$ 1(11)^*01(11)^* \enspace, $$

our goal is not to describe *some* of the words in $L$, but *all* of them.  This is not entirely trivial in this case; therefore let's take another, more systematic approach.

The strings in our language may start with any number of $0$s.  So, we are going to use $0^*$ as a building block.  A nonempty string of $1$s of odd length is given by $1(11)^*$.  That's another building block for our regular expression.  From $1(11)^*$ we get $1$, $111$, $11111$, and so on.

Finally, in between blocks of $1$s we can have any positive number of $0$s.  That is, $00^*$.  Let's now put these building blocks together:

$$ 0^* (1(11)^* 00^*)^* (1(11)^* + \epsilon) \enspace. $$

It's not the simplest regular expression out there, but we should be able to recognize the building blocks.  We start with an optional block of $0$s. Then we have zero or more blocks of $1$s of odd lengths, each followed by one or more zeros.  Finally, we have an optional block of $1$s (of odd length) not followed by $0$s to account for the fact that a word in $L$ may not have trailing $0$s.

This is not the only regular expression for $L$, as is often the case.  If you have already seen Kleene's Theorem, you should know of the systematic procedure alluded to by John Hughes in his comment.  For this $L$ it produces a regular expression of complexity comparable to the one above.